# how could I use data type IPHostEntry including while-loop between nest try-catch?

Tags: c#

I need to use  my own define struct between two try-catch block  ?

```
try
{
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");

    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
}
```

but the host was not visible in next try-catch?
how could I do to let the next try-catch to see the

```
IPHostEntry host
```

Inside the second try-catch?

I need to put a while-loop between two try-cach !!

```
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry host;

            while (host == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", 
                     e.ToString());
                }
            }  // end while
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", 
                     e.ToString());
         }
```

And the variable  host  have error use in while(host == null) ?

Comment: Why do you need 2 Try/Catch traps at all since you are not trapping specific exceptions?  Also,by definition, arent all exceptions unexpected?

Comment: The reason why I need 2 Try/Catch is that I would add a While-loop  inside the first Try/Catch

Comment: Since you're using a valid, hard-coded string for the server name, you only need to catch `SocketException` in the outer `catch` (though what you have is fine). `host` is certainly visible inside the second `try` (now that you've fixed the brackets). What is the question, or what problem are you seeing (exception? compile error? unexpected values?)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C# uses variable scoping with curly braces, so you just need to declare the variable in the parent scope, like so:

```
IPHostEntry host = default(IPHostEntry);

try
{
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");

    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0} {1}", e.ToString(), host);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per your updated code:

```
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry host = default(IPHostEntry);

        while (host == null)
        {
            try
            {
                host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", 
                 e.ToString());
            }
        }  // end while
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", 
                 e.ToString());
     }
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake describe in problem